# Error during execution of processor and Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring

I have written the bean name correctly both in
**UserController** and **index.html** page but still 
I am getting the  error, which is

```
---Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute.
```

Please help ....Thanks in advance

**Here is the controller**

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public ModelAndView indexPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        List<User> userList = userService.getAllUser();
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);
        return new ModelAndView("index");
      }
}
```

**Here is the html page**

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:tiles="http://www.thymeleaf.org" class="no-js">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myTable').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="height:20px;background:#85a3e0;">
    </div>
    <div class="container col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <h3 class="text-center">Super Admin</h3>
        <p id="alert" th:text="${successMsg}" style="margin-left:80%;color:green;"></p>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="margin-left: 6%;">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" th:action="@{/saveUser}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name">Username:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" class="form-control" id="name" th:field="*{userName}" />
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{userId}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" th:field="*{password}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--   <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="role">Role:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="role" placeholder="Enter role" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="priv">Privileges:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="priv" placeholder="Enter privileges" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class=" col-sm-12 text-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="cancel" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
                        <button id="btnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save" value="save">Save</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update" value="update">Update</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="delete" value="delete">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="overflow-x:100%;overflow-y:auto;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <select class=" ">
                    <option selected="selected" value="">User</option>
                    <option value="1">Admin</option>

                </select>
                <hr/>
                <table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Password</th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tr th:each="user : ${userList}">
                        <td><a th:text="${user.userName}" th:href="@{/viewUser(userId=${user.userId})}" /></td>
                        <td th:text="${user.password}"></td>


                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```